# Remove all files starting with a certain header

Tags: ubuntu

So I have a dataset that I want to use for my neural network.

The problem is that within the dataset there are files that were originally .BMP but thanks to a script I used they were converted to .JPG

I am trying to figure out how to get rid of these files automatically as I am dealing with a large amount of data and doing it manually isn't possible.

It's super easy to spot them in the file explorer (the thumbnail doesn't load and it simply says JPG) but I can't figure out an automated way to do it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ImageMagick’s “identify” command to tell the bitmap files apart. The rest should be a more or less straightforward scripting exercise, to go through your files and delete the right ones - or perhaps move them to a separate directory where you can inspect them before deletion to make sure you got only the ones you wanted rid of.

https://www.imagemagick.org

ImageMagick is quite cross-platform and well documented online. Here's sample output (from within Ubuntu):

```
anlag@jansson:~/Downloads/img$ identify lena_gray.bmp 
lena_gray.bmp BMP3 512x512 512x512+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 263KB 0.000u 0:00.000
anlag@jansson:~/Downloads/img$ identify photo.jpg 
photo.jpg JPEG 127x127 127x127+0+0 8-bit sRGB 7.51KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

You would parse the output for the "BMP3" string and process accordingly. The scripting itself could be done in whatever tool you’re comfortable with: Windows cmd.exe script, Python, bash etc. If you need a hand with that part too, it's probably best you specify with some more information about what OS and software you  use (scripting language/tool in particular).

PS. I referenced ImageMagick since it's cross-platform, but if you were to happen to be using Linux, the “file” command would give equivalent information for this use case.

```
anlag@jansson:~/Downloads/img$ file lena_gray.bmp 
lena_gray.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 512 x 512 x 8
anlag@jansson:~/Downloads/img$ file photo.jpg 
photo.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I figured out how to do it (I did it the same way you posted) and it worked flawlessly. Thanks!